# apt get is not working unmet dependencies

Tags: installation, server, apt, package-management

I tried installing the packages as below

```
apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext \
  libz-dev libssl-dev
```

then I got this error

```
    root@ip-10-233-139-125:~# apt-get -f install
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    Correcting dependencies... Done
    The following extra packages will be installed:
      openmrs
    Suggested packages:
      tomcat6-admin lcab cabextract
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      openmrs
    0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 137 not upgraded.
    1 not fully installed or removed.
    Need to get 0 B/34.1 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 34.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
    WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
      openmrs
    Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
    dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/openmrs_1.6.1_all.deb (--unpack):
     unable to open file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci//.svn': Is a directory
    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                  Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/openmrs_1.6.1_all.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

then I tried

```
root@ip-10-248-109-175:~# sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sana:
 sana depends on openmrs; however:
  Package openmrs is not installed.
dpkg: error processing sana (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sana
```

I removed the directory sana in /opt/ as I don't want that.
I tried some other

Comment: Where does openmrs come from? Have you added an external repository? Which one?

Comment: I added openmrs,java softwareusing tomcat but now I uninstalled tomcat also I m not finding openmrs with command `locate openmrs`  @mikewhatever

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get clean` to clean cached .debs.

Comment: this is working,can you make this solution,so that I will vote that.

Comment: Glad it helped. ...answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, cleaning the cached packages was a solution, and the following command does just that.

```
sudo apt-get clean
```